# Not able to add records to SQLite database

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a new table in my database. I added this table from the DB Browser for SQLite. I have also checked the existence of table from my code like so...

```
let isTable = sharedInstance.checkTableExistOrNot("eSMAT_List")
```

`isTable` return true indicating the table called `eSMAT_List` is present. There's an array called `arr_Entries`. I'm entering values from this array into my database like so...

```
                if arr_Entries.count != 0 {
                    let smatLists = eSMAT_List()
                    for i in 0..<(arr_Entries.count) {
                        self.dictionary = arr_Entries[i] as! NSMutableDictionary
                        smatLists.id = self.dictionary["id"]! as? Int
                        smatLists.Plant_Name = self.dictionary["plantName"]! as? String
                        smatLists.Department_Name = self.dictionary["departmentName"]! as? String
                        smatLists.Due_Date = self.dictionary["dueDate"]! as? String
                        smatLists.Smat_Leader1 = self.dictionary["smator"]! as? String
                        smatLists.Smat_Leader2 = self.dictionary["smator2"]! as? String
                        smatLists.Smat_Receiver1 = self.dictionary["smatee"]! as? String
                        smatLists.Smat_Receiver2 = self.dictionary["smatee2"]! as? String
                        smatLists.job_Name = self.dictionary["jobName"]! as? String
                        smatLists.workstation_Name = self.dictionary["workstationName"]! as? String

                        let isInserted = sharedInstance.saveESMAT_Lists(smatLists)
                        if(!isInserted)
                        {
                            isSync = false
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Now the function `saveESMAT_Lists` is given as...

```
func saveESMAT_Lists(_ items: eSMAT_List) -> Bool {
    var isInserted = false

    sharedInstance.database!.open()

    isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO eSMAT_List (Plant_Name,department_Name,Due_Date,smat_leader1,smat_leader2,smat_receiver1,smat_receiver2,jobName,workstationName,Plant_Id) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",withArgumentsIn: [items.Plant_Name!,items.Department_Name!,items.Due_Date!,items.Smat_Leader1!,items.Smat_Leader2 ?? "",items.Smat_Receiver1!,items.Smat_Receiver2 ?? "",items.job_Name!,items.workstation_Name!,items.id!])

    sharedInstance.database!.close()
    return isInserted
}
```

Now each of these variables `items.Plant_Name!,items.Department_Name!...etc.` also has values within them. But `isInserted` is always returning false indicating the data has not been saved to the database.

Comment: What library are you using, do you have any error handling in your code, have you tried to manually execute the insert statement?

Comment: Are you doing any concurrent insertions at the same time?

Comment: can you print data that is being inserted i doubt you have ' in your data or character that is n't producing error also check error logs as well if it's showing something.